# Sequencing Elektron Analog Rytm MKII & Elektron Analog Four MKI & Elektron Digitakt

Tags: synthesizer

I want to synchrone Elektron Analog Rytm MKII & Elektron Analog Four MKI & Elektron Digitakt.

This is my setup:

on the Elektron Analog Four MKI:

```
CLOCK RECEIVE -> ON
CLOCK SEND —> OFF
TRANSPORT RECEIVE -> ON
TRANSPORT SEND -> OFF
PROG. CH RECEIVE -> OFF
PROG CH. SEND -> OFF
```

on Elektron Digitakt:

```
CLOCK RECEIVE -> ON
CLOCK SEND —> ON
PROG. CH RECEIVE -> ON
PROG CH. SEND -> ON
```

ON Elektron Analog Rytm MKII :

```
CLOCK RECEIVE -> OFF
CLOCK SEND —> ON
TRANSPORT RECEIVE -> OFF
TRANSPORT SEND -> ON
PROG. CH RECEIVE -> OFF
PROG CH. SEND -> ON
```

and

```
MIDI IN Elektron Analog Rytm MKII <-> Sync A MIDI OUT Elektron Digitakt
Sync A MIDI OUT Elektron Analog Rytm MKII <-> MIDI IN Elektron Analog Four MKI
```

Elektron Analog Rytm MKII & Elektron Analog Four MKI are synchronized, but not the Elektron Digitakt, when I push play on  Elektron Analog Rytm MKII, only the Elektron Analog Four MKI starts to play with the same BPM of the Analog Rytm MKII, not the Digitakt

Comment: At that price, I'd be straight onto the manufacturers.

Comment: I am not using Overbridge or any other software

Comment: So the edited version of the question is about syncing, not about the signal path?

Comment: indeed...  is about syncing